# mysql_num_rows gives waring when no data found in database

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

I have a query which perform fine, but the problem is somehow its gives me the warning when no data match from database.

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($qry); //warning here
```

I can use `@` to hide the error, but this is not good programming as far i know, so how can i hide the warning from the output?

> **The Warning:** Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   resource, boolean given in [somepage.php] on line [11]

```
$count = @mysql_num_rows($qry); //No warning
```

So i know there will be the ways to hide the warning, but i don't know. please help me on this.

Comment: error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

Comment: What does this do??

Comment: Hide your warning from the current page on browser.

Comment: Yes, its working, thanks.

Comment: dont hide\suppress errors that's just stupid

Comment: so what should i do? @Dagon

Comment: Edit your php.ini and configure the errors section to not show warnings or use the define command. Search for it. Also consider in changing your `mysql_*` functions it is deprecated change it to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: What is the actual warning?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, Updated Question with warning.

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions. use prepared statement

Comment: That warning tells you that you should have checked the return value of the previous statement.  The error obviously lies in the query itself.  Not getting any result from a query is **very** different from getting an error, so you should investigate it by running the query directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Some folks are saying you should work around this issue by suppressing warnings. Don't listen to them -- warnings are telling you that something is wrong. Suppressing them defeats their entire purpose.

I'm also assuming you know that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated in favor of [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Others have mentioned this and they're absolutely right -- there are a bunch of security issues with the `mysql` extension. It's so bad that if you want to upgrade to PHP 7 you'll be forced to use `mysqli` because `mysql` has been completely removed.

But in general, when something returns a resource on success and `false` on failure, you can check for failure before using the resource. Like so:

```
$rslt = mysql_query($query);
if (!$rslt)
{
    // handle error
}
else
{
    $count = mysql_num_rows($rslt);
    // ...
}
```

As an alternative to checking result as a boolean, you could swap the cases and use [is_resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Better to not use mysql_* at all